# Is Brahmakumaris Hindu organization? Why Brahmakumaris say 2036 is end or the judgement day ? is it true?

Tags: belief, calendar, brahmakumaris

Is Brahmakumaris Hindu organization? Why do they claim that [2036 will be end](http://www.brahmakumari.net/the-end-1996-2000-2012-or-2036) of world?

They claim that flood will take place and then ice age will come.

Recently Scientists said that [around 2030 to 2040 mini ice age will come](http://www.washingtontimes.com/news/2015/jul/12/mini-ice-age-likely-from-2030-to-2040-european-sci/).

Recently I visited them they say natural calamities will end the world. America and Russia will raise world war. Is it true? One earthquake will destroy the entire america and another will destroy whole china.

Brahmakumaris say we do not have much time, 2036 is very long period. but it is estimated that it can be very short. It is unexpected to predict when the war will start.

If so according to them this is time to pray. They say leave everything and pray to Shiva. This is time to go back to Paramdham, which is home to souls this world is not home of souls.

**Is this true that 2036 will be the end of the world?**

Comment: No, my blood sister follow Brahmakumaris. They are not Hindu, means anyone can follow them. They are just groups of afraid people who think Bhagwadgeeta is written by Lord Shiva, not by all mighty Krishna. They have were annoying rule for living, and they dont know why they are doing these.

Comment: Ice age doesn't mean end of the world. Many Hindu cults have internalized this nonsense of end of the world from Abrahamic religions. Even 'Pralaya' in the Hindu mythology isn't the end but just a stage before the world is restarted. Isn't the absolute end.

Comment: There are many theories on internet that around 2035 world war 3 will happen and a "spiritual man" (kalki?) from India will conquer almost Asia and some parts of Europe. Half of the Indian population will be reduced during those 30 years. We cannot say anthing about these prophecies untill we experience them.

Comment: @VipulHadiya Yeah Bhagavad Gita was a discourse between Krishna and Arjuna but if it happened between Shiva and Arjuna then also it would have been fine. Why are they afraid?

Comment: Everything is fine but the thing is what Brahmakumaris say is true? If so according to them this is time to pray. They say leave everything and pray to Shiva. This is time to go back to Paramdham.

Comment: I'm a part of it and it's true. The world will end. If you doubt them and their perceptions and actually the TRUTH. Then, you should go and meet them once. They're Holy great people who just tell you to inherit all the goodness in you. They're just perfect.

Comment: @VipulHadiya I agree with you Bramhakumaris are not hindus, they are just fairy tale people who think there is no form of Bramhan (they are not even consistent with Vedanta and BG) www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-12-5/

Comment: I dont think they believe in no form of brahman. They promote Shivalingams and Shiva as a brahman. So please do not change the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They don't say Shiva as a brahman.. Shiva means formless. Shiva is the name of god. Shiva and shankar both r different. Shiva is formless supreme being-our father(God). Shankar is a diety. In the end of kaliyuga(today's age of crime), God incarnates through a normal human being(which later he names brahma) and take his body as a medium to give supreme knowledge and do the secret task of world transformation and bringing a new age of goodness(satyuga or golden age). Now this time has come. Brahmakumaris are just followers of God who has incarnated through brahma and participated in the process of world transformation.

Comment: You should cite sources. Please visit [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/125/3500)

Comment: @The Destroyed You are always asking others to cite resources. That's a good thing. Recently you deleted one of my answers. I ask you where is it written that answer that has no citation has to be deleted? Please provide citation for your action.

Comment: @Lokesh I have replied you clearly in flag. Your answer was converted to comment as it looks like comment. See https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/803/3500

Comment: Oh. I didn't knew it was converted to comment. Thanks for providing sources.